# Place an image behind my labels and in front of my plot within my coreplot graph

Tags: iphone, graph, label, core-plot, layer

How can I get an image behind my labels within my graph. I succeeded with putting an image in front of the graph with:

```
   CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *imageAnnotation;
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 480, 320);
    CPTBorderedLayer * ImageLayer = [[CPTBorderedLayer alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
    ImageLayer.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Overlay_3_digits.png"] CGImage]]];
    imageAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:plotSpace anchorPlotPoint:nil];
    imageAnnotation.contentLayer = ImageLayer;
    [graph addAnnotation:imageAnnotation];
    [graph addSublayer:ImageLayer];
    [newImagelLayer release];
    [imageAnnotation release];
```

adding the image with [graph insertSubLayer:ImageLayer below:y]; didn't worked, this also puts the image in front of the graphs and axislabels. Hope someone can help me out.

EDIT:
I added a screenshot from the simulator. The three black rectangles needs to be in front of my plots and behind my labels. The labels will be readible more easily.

[image: Simulator screenshot of my graph]

I also editted the hierarchy of layers from my graph by putting the axislabels at the first index:

```
NSArray *chartLayers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisLabels],
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypePlots],
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeMajorGridLines], 
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeMinorGridLines],  
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisLines], 
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisTitles],

                                                            nil];
    graph.topDownLayerOrder = chartLayers;
```

I also found a better way of putting my image inside the graph. I did this by means of a new hostlayer:

```
CPTAnnotationHostLayer *newHostLayer = [[CPTAnnotationHostLayer alloc]
                                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 220)];
    UIImage * annotationBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Overlay_3_digits.png"];    

    newHostLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:annotationBG].CGColor;
```

Any ideas how I can put the three black triangle image at the back of my labels and in front of the plots?

Answer (score 0):

The `-addAnnotation:` method takes care of updating the layer tree; you should remove your call to `-addSublayer:`.

Do you want the image to completely fill the background behind the graph? If so, just set the `fill` on the graph instead of making an annotation.

```
graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Overlay_3_digits.png"] CGImage]]];
```

To put the box behind each label, you can use custom labels. Build a `CPTBorderedLayer` the same way you did for the annotation. Add a `CPTTextLayer` with the label text as a sublayer of the bordered layer. Make the bordered layer the `contentLayer` of the custom label. This should remove the need to change the `topDownLayerOrder`, too.

Comment: I want the images to be placed in front of my graph and behind axislabels I changed the hierarchy of graph.topDownLayerOrder so that axislabels are on top I succeeded adding an image -> CPTAnnotationHostLayer *newHostLayer = [[CPTAnnotationHostLayer alloc]
                                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 220)];
    UIImage * annotationBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rechts.png"];    
    
    newHostLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:annotationBG].CGColor;

the final line:   [graph insertSublayer:newHostLayer below:y]; places my image op top of the labels

Comment: Any ideas how I can change the hierarchy so that my newly created hostLayer is at the back of the labels and in front of the plots? Maybe removing the y axis and setting it again in a new sublayer, which enables me to set the new hostlayer as a sublayer below the axislayer?

Comment: My feeling is you're over thinking this and making it more complicated that it needs to be, but I can't picture what you're trying to do well enough to articulate a solution. Can you post a mockup image of the effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I editted my answer. Do you have an idea Eric, guess you're the coreplot pro ;)